# How to parse files with arbitrary lengths?

Tags: parsing, go, text

I have a text file that I'd like to parse with records like this:

```
===================
name: John Doe
Education: High School Diploma
Education: Bachelor's Degree
Education: Sun Java Certified Programmer
Age: 29
===================
name: Bob Bear
Education: High School Diploma
Age: 18
===================
name: Jane Doe
Education: High School Diploma
Education: Bachelor's Degree
Education: Master's Degree
Education: AWS Certified Solution Architect Professional
Age: 25
```

As you can see, the `fields` in such a text file are fixed, but some of them repeat an arbitrary number of times. The records are separated by a fixed  length `====` delimiter.

How would I write parsing logic this this sort of problem? I am think of using `switch` as it reads the start of the line, but the logic to handle multiple repeating fields baffles me.

Comment: How would you do that if you needed to parse it manually, with a piece of paper and a pencil?

Comment: @zerkms why are you teaching me how to fish?

I'd go through once and separate each record. ( as in each person ) Then for each _person_ record, run a switch statement to parse the fields, and store them in an appropriate struct. e.g the `Education` field could be a list so it could hold multiple entries.

Comment: This question is very broad and not well suited for SO in its current status. Please read up on parsing or come up with a simple way of your own (this is not that hard of a problem), then come back here with concrete code examples if you have a problem. I would simple strings.Split by \n and go from there. Compare for "=============" to find the separator. Use strings.Index to find the first colon in a line, etc.

Comment: @gonutz That's the approach I'm taking. I guess I was looking for an elegant example I could base my code upon. Looks like it's better If I come back with some code so it could be scrutinized

Comment: @mindrunner "why are you teaching me how to fish?" --- probably because the strategy you chose to solve programming problems does not work for you. But whatever.

Comment: @zerkms I meant it in a self-reflectory way. Maybe a smiley might have helped to convey the context. Anyway, translating the on paper to code approach has helped. maerics ' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51678545/962561)  where the methodology is described was actually what I was looking for. But your summary helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to approach this sort of problem is to "divide and conquer". That is, divide the overall problem into smaller sub-problems which are easier to manage and then solve each them individually.  If you've planned properly then when you've finished each of the sub-problems you should have solved the whole problem.

Start by thinking about modeling. The document appears to contain a list of records, what should those records be called? What named fields should the records contain and what types should they have? How would you represent them idiomatically in go? For example, you might decide to call each record a `Person` with fields as such:

```
type Person struct {
    Name        string
    Credentials []string
    Age         int
}
```

Next, think about what the interface (signature) of your parse function should look like. Should it emit an array of people? Should it use a visitor pattern and emit a person as soon as it's parsed? What constraints should drive the answer? Are memory or compute time constraints important? Does the user of the parser want any control over the parsing work such as canceling? Do they need metadata such as the total number of records contained in the document? Will the input always be from a file or a string, maybe from an HTTP request or a network socket? How will these choices drive your design?

```
func ParsePeople(string) ([]Person, error) // ?
func ParsePeople(io.Reader) ([]Person, error) // ?
func ParsePeople(io.Reader, func visitor(Person) bool) error // ?
```

Finally you can implement your parser to fulfill the interface that you've decided on. A straightforward approach here would be to read the input file line-by-line and take an action according to the contents of the line. For example (in pseudocode):

```
forEach line = inputFile.line
  if line is a separator
    emit or store the last parsed person, if present
    create a new person to store parsed fields
  else if line is a data field
    parse the data
    update the person with the parsed data
  end
end
return the parsed records or final record, if emitting
```

Each line of pseudocode above represents a sub-problem that should be easier to solve than the whole.

Comment: My question was sort of badly worded. But you understood the gist of what I was asking. Thanks for that. This can be applied to other programming problems I have as well, so cheers for that.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Add explanation of why I just post a program as answer.

I am presenting a very straight forward implementation to parse the text you have given in your question. You accepted maerics answer and that is OK. I want to add some counter arguments to his answer, though. Basically the pseude-code in that answer is a non-compilable version of the code in my answer so we agree on the solution to this.

What I do not agree with is the over-engineering talk. I have to deal with code written by over-thinkers everyday. I urge you NOT to think about patterns, memory and time constraints or who might want what from this in the future.

Visitor pattern? That is something that is pretty much only useful in parsing programming languages, do not try to construct a use-case for it out of this problem. The visitor pattern is for traversing trees with different types of things in it. Here we have a list, not a tree, of things that are all the same.

Memory and time constraints? Are you parsing 5 GB of text with this? Then this might be a real concern. But even if you do, always write the simplest thing first. It will suffice. Throughout my career I only ever needed to use something other then a simple array or apply a complicated algorithm at most once per year. Still I see code everywhere that uses complicated data structures and algorithms without reason. This complicates change, is errorprone, sometimes makes things slower eventually! Do not use an observable list abstraction that notifies all observers whenever its contents change - but wait, let's add an update lock and unlock so we can control when to NOT notify everybody... No! Do not go down that route. Use a slice. Do your logic. Make everything read easy from top to bottom. I do not want to jump from A to B to C, chasing interfaces, following getters to finally find not a concrete data type but yet another interface. That is not the way to go.

These are the reasons why my code does not export anything, it is a self-contained, runnable example, a concrete solution to your concrete problem. You can read it, it is easy to follow. It is not heavily commented because it does not need to be. The three comments are not stating what happens but why it happens. Everything else is evident from the code itself. I left the note about the potential error in there on purpose. You know what kind of data you have, there is no line in there where this bug would be triggered. Do not write code to handle what cannot happen. If in the future someone would add a line without a text after the colon (remember, nobody will ever do this, do not worry about it), this will trigger a panic, point you to this line, you add another if or something, you are done. This code is future proof more then a program that tries to handle all kinds of different non-existent variations of the input.

The main point that I want to stretch is: write only what is necessary to solve the problem at hand. Everything beyond that makes your program hard to read and change, it will be untested and unnecessary.

With that said, here is my original answer:

https://play.golang.org/p/T6c51jSM5nr

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    type item struct {
        name       string
        educations []string
        age        int
    }
    var items []item

    var current item
    finishItem := func() {
        if current.name != "" { // handle the first ever separator
            items = append(items, current)
        }
        current = item{}
    }

    lines := strings.Split(code, "\n")
    for _, line := range lines {
        if line == separator {
            finishItem()
        } else {
            colon := strings.Index(line, ":")
            if colon != -1 {
                id := line[:colon]
                value := line[colon+2:] // note potential bug if text has nothing after ':'
                switch id {
                case "name":
                    current.name = value
                case "Education":
                    current.educations = append(current.educations, value)
                case "Age":
                    age, err := strconv.Atoi(value)
                    if err == nil {
                        current.age = age
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finishItem() // in case there was no separator at the end

    for _, item := range items {
        fmt.Printf("%s, %d years old, has educations:\n", item.name, item.age)
        for _, e := range item.educations {
            fmt.Printf("\t%s\n", e)
        }
    }
}

const separator = "==================="

const code = `===================
name: John Doe
Education: High School Diploma
Education: Bachelor's Degree
Education: Sun Java Certified Programmer
Age: 29
===================
name: Bob Bear
Education: High School Diploma
Age: 18
===================
name: Jane Doe
Education: High School Diploma
Education: Bachelor's Degree
Education: Master's Degree
Education: AWS Certified Solution Architect Professional
Age: 25`
```